# Retrieving Standard Report Folder using Metadata api

Tags: metadata-api

I am trying to retrieve Standard report folder names using metadata api.

```
 MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
 List < MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery > queries = new List < MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery > ();
 service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
 service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();

 MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery queryDocumentFolder = new MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery();
 queryDocumentFolder.type_x = 'ReportFolder';
 queries.add(queryDocumentFolder);
 MetadataService.FileProperties[] fileProperties = service.listMetadata(queries, 30);
```

But I am getting only custum folder names and 'unfiled$public' folder name.I want to know,Is it possible to get other standard report folder names?

Thanks

Comment: Probably yes if they are public. Did you check if standard folders are public?

Comment: Yes they are public